# Error when creating a simple Backbone Model using Backbone 0.9.10

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to create a very simple Backbone Model and I am consistently getting an error.

```
<script src="/dugoutServices/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"</script>
<script src="/dugoutServices/js/backbone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Team = Backbone.Model.extend({});
</script>
```

This throws the following error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_.has(protoProps, 'constructor')')

The Backbone docs say this function is looking to see if the constructor property was overridden, if not it uses the default parent constructor. For some reason it is having an issue when searching for this constructor property.

I have tried adding an initialize() method and that did not work. This simple code worked when using Backbone 0.3.3. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have an error in your code syntax which prevents underscore.js from loading. Fix the missing `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the version of `underscore` you're using doesn't have the `_.has` method.  If you update your version of underscore it should run fine.

Comment: I had no idea underscore.js was a dependency for simple backbone models. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"</script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

You're missing a `>`.

Comment: That was a typo in the post - sorry it got lost when copying and pasting.